# sequelize migration doesnot read dotenv variables

Tags: sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

When I start server, it connects to database well.
In my case the command is `nodemon`

But when I try to migrate. the command is `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` I got connect ECONNREFUSED error.

I found that the problem was process.env
If I put in the very string on username, password, database , host, it works well!
but I think when migrate, It is not passed well
I’m using dotenv
how can I pass right config value..?

Any advice would be thankful.

This is my config file

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
      underscored: true
    }
  },
  development_light: {
    username: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
      underscored: true
    }
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
      underscored: true
    }
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.PROD_DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
      underscored: true
    }
  }
};
```

And this is error I got when I trying to migrate

```
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
(node:90780) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out.
it worked well when I db:migrate in the root directory. (I edited .sequelizerc file to point config, migrations, etc files from the root directory.)
I guess it is because the root directory is where the .env file exists

when I try to db:migrate from sequelize directory, it still doesn’t work  with a connection error,.

But I’m not confident with my guess yet